# How do I find the Number of Solutions to an equation from a discrete math point of view?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Hi I'm trying to figure out a better understanding of my discrete math class as my notes and professor aren't the clearest.

I think I got the first part but I get lost easily when more restrictions are applied. Here is the question(s):

[image]

I haven't made it far so for the two I don't have an answer for, I'll state my guess/what I think is needed and update this as feedback is provided :) Don't judge the stupidity of my guesses please.

### Here are my solutions/attempts:

a.) **$x_i$'s are nonnegative integers:** $c(40+7-1,7-1) = c(46,6) = 9366819$ ?

b.) **$x_i$'s are nonnegative integers and $x_1 \le 3$**:

instead of c(46,6), would you subtract 3? so c(43,6)

c.) **$x_i$'s are nonnegative integers and $x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7$ are positive:**

Would you take $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and do: c(40+3-1,7-4) = c(42,3) ... then similarly do the same with $x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7$: c(40+4-1,7-3) = c(43,4) .. and simply add them? so: **c(42,3)+c(43,4)**?

Feedback and tips are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Generally nonnegative implies $a\ge0$. Positive means $a\gt0$. Can you do it now?

Comment: (b) is wrong.  It might be better to look at $x_1=0,1,2,3$ in turn

Comment: @Sabyasachi Oh ok that makes sense lol. Would that make it just one less than part a? so c(45,6)? I really don't understand how to restrict the results :(

Comment: @Sabyasachi i updated my work for part c.) if you wouldn't mind checking it to see if i'm getting closer.

Comment: @Cozen there's an easier way. for every integer that is greater than zero, it means it is greater than equal to 1. substitute that integer by another variable say $t_i + 1$. Now $t_i \ge 0$. Now it is converted to part a. easy. :D happy math

Comment: I want to bounty this question